# Set the value of an html textfield with a php variable using echo

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to grab a name from a database and then created a textfield with the value preset to that name.  I'm creating the textfield by echoing it out with php and setting the value to the name.  However the variable i put in the value is not running it's just printing out as {$c->prod_name} instead of the actual name.

Here is my query:

```
function name_id($id) {
    global $pdo;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
        SELECT prod_name
        FROM products
        WHERE id = '$id'
        LIMIT 50");

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );   
}
```

Here is where i echo out the text field:

```
<?php

    $name = name_id($id);

    foreach($name as $c){

        echo '<input name="prod_name" type="text" size="50" value="{$c->prod_name}" ?>';

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two glitches in your code

Addressing your problem: `it's just printing out as {$c->prod_name}`:

For your `echo` statement you use single quotes `'`. Variables and escape sequences (other than `\'` and `\\`) are not expanded inside single quotes. That means, the `$` and `{}` have no special meaning and are outputted as plain text, not as variable (see [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)). You need to move the variable out of the string and use concatenation if you want to use single quotes, like that:

```
echo '<input name="prod_name" type="text" size="50" value="' . {$c->prod_name} . '" ?>';
```

Glitch #2 in your `name_id` function: Change the lines to the following:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT prod_name
    FROM products
    WHERE id = ?
    LIMIT 50");

$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

If you are importing the variable into the prepare string, you are not preventing XSS attacks, etc. - see [php.net PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @lazyhammer for his suggested edit. I don't know why it was rejected as it improves my answer a lot.

Answer (score 0):

replace all occurences of single quotes ' with double "

and vice versa

change this :

```
  echo '<input name="prod_name" type="text" size="50" value="{$c->prod_name}" />'; ?>
```

to this:

```
echo "<input name='prod_name' type='text' size='50' value='{$c->prod_name}'/>"; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The "echo-ing" of a variable in a string statement like this only works with `"` (double qoutes). Therefore, you could `escape` a lot of the double quotes like so:

```
echo "<input name=\"prod_name\" type=\"text\" size=\"50\" value=\"{$c->prod_name}\">"; ?>
```

but it is so much easier to just `concatenate` the string like so:

```
echo '<input name="prod_name" type="text" size="50" value="'.$c->prod_name.'">'; ?>
```

The simplest answer is: when you "inline" a variable it **MUST** be in double quotations:

`echo "{$c->prod_name}";`